# Bit twiddling for Java or Scala programmers

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Does anyone know of good tutorials or even a good book to master bit-level operations? I mean it's almost clear what every operation does (in Java for instance) or where to find the right documentation, but I'm very new to this topic and I wonder how things like:

```
// Find a power of 2 >= initialCapacity
int capacity = 1;
while (capacity < initialCapacity)
    capacity <<= 1;
```

work (copied from `HashMap`). I can't imagine how Integers, Longs or whatever data type are affected by bit operations :-(

I mean I don't want to know every kind of operation, just what seems to be fundamental to high level programmers in Java or Scala like the example provided.

Another example would be:

```
/**
 * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
 * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
 * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
 * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
 * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
 */
static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

That just seems to be magic :(

Comment: Hackers Delight [ capacity <<= 1 is effectively capacity *= 2 ], side note the algorithm is not the most effective to find the next pow2 >=capacity, for instance this should be better: `1 << (32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(initialCapacity - 1))` or even `initialCapacity>1?Integer.highestOneBit(initialCapacity-1)<<1:initialCapacity`

Comment: I've already heard of this book, but I'm not sure if it's something for even the basics?

Comment: you want to "master" it, for starter anything explaining binary arithmetics will do.

Comment: about the edit and the magic, well the extra hashing is indeed sort of magic and tried to spread "more" information into the lower bits as the higher ones are effective unused.  So even a good hash function generates well distributed hashes but similar in the lower bits, HashMap may degrade into a linked list.

Comment: TAOCP v4A has a nice chapter on it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand the basics, you need to understand how data is represented.  This requires understanding binary and  usually [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Once you understand the basics, a lot of useful hacks can be found at the [ubiquitous Stanford source](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Answer (score 3):

this seems to be a good link,

[http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060_*Operators/0300*_Bitwise-Operators.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/0300__Bitwise-Operators.htm)

on first link, it displays the comprehensive table, and then the link for detail of operation follows. hope it helps.

Comment: it's http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/0300__Bitwise-Operators.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just cannot resist...

**A Short Bit Manipulation Tutorial**

Integers are represented with binary codes. Two's complement is not the only possible encoding, but it is what is now used (almost?) everywhere.

For 3 bits, the binary codes are:

```
000  0
001  1
010  2
011  3
100  4
101  5
110  6
111  7
```

If we added 1 to 7, we would get the code `1000`, but we have only 3 bits, so we get `000`. This is called overflow. It may sound strange, but overflow is almost always ignored at the compiler level (*). It's up to the programmer to choose a data type with the appropriate range (int, long, BigInteger...).

But we have seen only positive numbers, where do we get negative numbers? A sign bit comes to mind, but we cannot add more bits, we have to use the bits that we have. So we assign the codes whose leftmost bit is 1 to negative numbers:

```
code  signed  unsigned
100     -4
101     -3
110     -2
111     -1
000      0       0
001      1       1
010      2       2
011      3       3
------------------
100              4
101              5
110              6
111              7
```

We see some asymmetry: there is a code for -4 but no code for 4. This is because we have to use one code for 0.

With signed 3-bit math, if we add 1 to 3, we get -4. This is overflow. And it is ignored at the compiler level.

So unsigned overflow happens between 111 and 000, whereas signed overflow happens between 011 and 100. This is why both overflows are ignored (*): if we ignore overflow, we can use the same addition for signed and unsigned numbers. (This also applies to subtraction and multiplication; only division is different for signed and unsigned numbers.)

And now, bit manipulation basics:

- "bit is set" means that the bit is `1`, "cleared" or "reset" means that the bit is `0`
- all negative numbers have the leftmost bit (most-significant bit, MSB) set, the positive numbers have MSB=0
- all odd numbers have the least significant bit (LSB, the rightmost bit) set, for even numbers LSB is reset (to zero)
- `(x & 1) == 1` for odd numbers, `(x & 1) == 0` for even numbers
- `x & -2` clears the least-significant bit of x; if x is odd, `(x & -2) == x-1`, and if x is even, `(x & -2) == x`
- `x & -4` clears two least-significant bits of x, etc.
- `(x << 1) == x*2`
- `(x >> 1) == x/2`
- `(x >>> 1) == x/2` (unsigned)
- you can use `+ - *` for unsigned math in Java and Scala, you will just have to write `unsignedToString` conversion yourself. And unsigned comparison will also be a problem.
- `(x ^ -1) == ~x == -x-1`
- `-x == (~x) + 1`
- `2**N` has one set bit followed by N zero bits (here `**` means power), e.g. `2**4 = 16 = 10000`
- `2**N - 1` is a value of N set bits, e.g. `2^4 - 1 = 15 = 1111`

As to the hash function, they do not get any meaningful value, they just get a value where many bits participate. You see, hash values should (ideally) be different for different meaningful values. If they took just some least-significant bits, all numbers like 1K, 2K, 3K would get into the same HashMap bucket, so they use bits from different parts of the number's code. They could use addition for combining the bits, but they preferred XOR (eXclusive OR).

(*) All CPUs have "flags" for both signed and unsigned overflow, but these flags cannot be accessed from the high-level languages because these flags are a side effect of CPU instructions like addition, subtraction, etc., and the flags after `r=r+(-1)` and `r=r-1` will be different (in the 1st case, we get unsigned overflow if `r!=0`; in the 2nd case, we get unsigned overflow if `r==0`). And, well, "unsigned overflow" is called carry/borrow, whereas "signed overflow" is usually called just overflow.